# Associatedtype usage inside Protocols and Generic functions

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, swift-protocols

Let's assume I've a `protocol Foo` with an `associatedtype Bar`. Is there any way to use this same **associatedtype** as a constraint in a generic function inside this same protocol?

To illustrate:

```
protocol Foo {
    associatedtype Bar
    func example<T: Bar>() -> T
}
```

This will throw a `Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'Self.Bar'`. Which makes total sense, because at compile-time, **we don't know which type Bar will be**.

Nonetheless, for some reason, even if I define the Bar type, I will still get the same error. Something like this:

```
protocol Foo {
    associatedtype Bar: NSObject //OR: Protocol
    func example<T: Bar>() -> T //Compile Error: Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'Self.Bar'
}
```

Both [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46022954/protocol-with-associatedtype-protocol-for-generic-functions) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676174/protocol-having-generic-function-and-associatedtype) questions address the same issue, but none of them are real answers in my honest opinion.

Also, maybe I'm approaching this in a wrong perspective of the language, but to visualize my use case: I need that when the class defines the type of `Bar`, each `T` used in `example()` function, should be a `Bar` type, but knowing which type it will return.
To illustrate what would be my state of art:

```
protocol Foo {
    associatedtype Bar: NSObject //OR: Protocol
    //Compile Error: Inheritance from non-protocol, non-class type 'Self.Bar'
    func example<T: Bar>() -> T //OR: func example<T>() -> T where T: Bar
}

class ExampleBarType: NSObject { }

class ExampleObject: ExampleBarType { }

class FooImplementation: Foo {
    typealias Bar = ExampleBarType

    func example<T: Bar>() -> T { //OR: func example<T>() -> T where T: Bar {

    }
}
```

I just can't seem to grasp why the compiler can't assume that my associatedtype will be the one that I've defined. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

What you're designing here isn't possible to implement. This isn't a Swift problem; I mean it's literally not possible to implement because the types don't make the promises you need. Consider this part:

```
class ExampleBarType {} // Not an NSObject subclass.

class FooImplementation: Foo {
    typealias Bar = ExampleBarType

    func example<T: Bar>() -> T {
        // What would you write here?
    }
}
```

How do you plan to write that function body? Consider the following caller:

```
class MyBar: Bar {        
    init(x: Int) {}
}

let ex: MyBar = foo.example()
```

How would you implement `example`? How can you construct `MyBar`? You don't know the parameters for the `init` method (it requires an Int that you don't have). But your function signature claims that this function will return whatever specific subclass of `Bar` the caller requests.

In general you should avoid mixing protocols, generics, and subclassing in the same type system. They pull in different directions and it is very difficult to keep your system coherent. You're going to wind up with a lot of cases where you can't fulfill your promises.

You should go back to your concrete problem and need. If you're doing this "because I want to be as generic as possible," I recommend stopping. The Swift type system is very powerful, but also has some very tricky limitations, and "as generic as possible just because" almost always slams into those restrictions. If you have a concrete use case in a real program, however, you often (though not always) can avoid those headaches.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an advanced topic. May this way can give you some lights.

```
protocol Foo {
associatedtype Bar: NSObject //OR: Protocol
func example() -> Bar  //OR:
}

class ExampleBarType: NSObject { }

class ExampleObject: ExampleBarType { }

class FooImplementation: Foo {
typealias Bar = ExampleBarType
func example<T: Bar>() -> T {
    return Bar.init() as! T
}
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this is currently the workaround I'm using, and it's exactly what I didn't wanted to do - to cast the return of my Type `T` -, but thanks for the tip.

Comment: What happens if I call `let x: BarSubclass = foo.example()`? I would expect that to crash. A `Bar` can't be as-cast to `BarSubclass`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm fully understanding your use case but, isn't this enough for doing what you need to do?

```
protocol Foo {
    associatedtype Bar
    func example() -> Bar
}

protocol BarProtocol { }

class BarOne: BarProtocol { }

class BarTwo: BarProtocol { }

class FooImplementationOne: Foo {
    func example() -> BarProtocol {
        return BarOne()
    }
}

class FooImplementationTwo: Foo {
    func example() -> BarProtocol {
        return BarTwo()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering. But no, this doesn't solve, mainly because I would always need to cast the return of example. Using your example for instance, the function `FooImplementationOne` `example()` function should return a `BarOne` instance, and `FooImplementationTwo` `example()` function should explicitly return a `BarTwo` instance. When you remove the generics from the `example()` function, it just knows that the type is `BarProtocol` meaning that I would've to cast everytime I wanted its type.